# Duplicate question request for reconsideration

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Upgrading raring to saucy on arm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509242/upgrading-raring-to-saucy-on-arm)

This question is closed as a dup.

I claim that [Are raring arm packages available someplace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509234/are-raring-arm-packages-available-someplace) is actually the dup, it's the question that asks 'where are the packages'.

[Upgrading raring to saucy on arm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509242/upgrading-raring-to-saucy-on-arm) is a question about a problem that arose *after* I'd already taken the step called for by the duplicate target.

If you follow the link to the chat I had with muru, you will see that the problem is not at all that I didn't have the right old-releases URL in sources.list, but rather that something apparently arm-specific goes wrong with do-release-upgrade, which is not related to sources.list *at all*.